# Problems enabling remote voltage-sense Rigol load DL3021 via SCPI

Tags: test-equipment, automation, electronic-load, scpi

I am automating some tests with Rigol hardware. There is only one bottleneck in the SCPI implementation that I can't figure out: **How to enable the remote voltage-sense terminals on the Rigol DP3021 through SCPI commands.**

It seems to be undocumented in the Rigol [programming manual](https://www.batronix.com/files/Rigol/Elektronische-Lasten/DL3000/DL3000_ProgrammingManual_EN.pdf).
I found some undocumented commands in this [EEVBlog topic](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/lists-of-rigol-scpi-commands/): the relevant command appears to be `:REMote:SENSe:STATe`

If I manually enable and disable the sense terminals, I can query this register `:REMote:SENSe:STATe?` and see the boolean status change as expected: `0/1 = Disable/Enable`.
However, if I write to this register `:REMote:SENSe:STATe 1` the physical sense terminal does not change state *unless* I seize local-control and open the `Utility` menu. Only then does the device physically switch to the remote sense terminals - I can hear the relay click and the screen shows the status.

It's as if opening the `Utility` menu triggers some status update.

Can somebody with SCPI experience comment?

*For now*, my work-around will have to be to manually enable the sense terminal every time the device is powered-up. I'm honestly a little bummed out that this isn't documented in the programming manual as it seems to be such a fundamental function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

First check if you have the latest firmware and then use the latest datasheet, because yours is from 2017 and the latest is from April 2019 ([programming guide](https://int.rigol.com/Public/Uploads/uploadfile/files/ftp/DL/%E6%89%8B%E5%86%8C/DL3000/EN/DL3000_ProgrammingGuide_EN.pdf)).

The SCPI commands you are looking for are:

> [:SOURce]:SENSe {0|1|ON|OFF}
> [:SOURce]:SENSe?

Comment: Fantastic - after all that I was just referring to the old programming manual. Thanks for your input, appreciate it!